# Как извлечь верхний тег?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть некая конструкция `Html`:

```
<div class='class'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='myCheckbox' />
</div>
```

Я беру этот элемент `checkbox`

```
var checkBox = document.getElementById('myCheckbox');
```

И вопрос в том, как мне взять элемент `DIV`, в котором этот чекбокс находится? Под элементом DIV *только* один элемент - `checkbox`.

P.S. Без использования библиотек.

Comment: с помощью jQuery:
``$('#myCheckBox').parent();``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var div = document.getElementById('myCheckBox').parentNode;
```

Comment: Да, верно. Спасибо